# How to fill colors in some specific area in R?

Tags: r, plot, fill

Here is the problem:

```
x<-seq(0,10,length.out = 1000)
y1<-dnorm(x,mean = 2,sd=1)
y2<-dnorm(x,mean = 6,sd=1)
plot(x,y1,type="l")
lines(x,y2)
abline(v=x[380])
```

The graph is shown below. How can I fill 2 different colors, say red and blue, on the each side of vertical line but still below two normal density functions. I thought I can use polygon, but failed.

This is the graph without filling colors:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to fill below the max of the two densities, or do you want the area under the two densities filled with different colors (perhaps with some transparency so you can see the overlap)?

Comment: @Gregor one is the part on the right side of the vertical line but below the right tail of the left normal density, the other is the part on the left side but below the left tail of the right normal density. Sorry for wording badly........

Comment: No worries, - so at any `x` point, you only want to fill up to the lowest density - or stated another way you want to fill the intersections/overlap of the densities. (The different colors on either side of the vertical line is very clearly stated.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's one way:

First, we'll get the *parallel minimum* of your densities - this is a vector of the top `y` coordinates for our polygons.

```
y = pmin(y1, y2)

# set up your plot as in the question    
plot(x, y1, type="l")
lines(x, y2)

# define a re-usable variable for the vertical line placement
x_vert = 380
abline(v = x[x_vert])

# Now we'll draw 2 polygons, one for the left side, one for the right.
# The first (x,y) pairs of the polygon are just the (x,y) coords of the
# density we're filling to, until the vertical line
# Then we need to connect the "bottom" points, which have coordinates
# (x[x_vert], 0) and (x[1], 0)    
polygon(x = c(x[1:x_vert], x[x_vert], x[1]), 
        y = c(y[1:x_vert], 0, 0),
        col = "blue")
# similar for the right hand polygon, but now going from x_vert to length(x)
polygon(x = c(x[x_vert:length(x)], x[length(x)], x[x_vert]),
        y = c(y[x_vert:length(x)], 0, 0),
        col = "red")
```

Voila!

[image]